# Appium installation on Windows through npm

Tags: appium

I am unable to install appium properly through npm .
I tried using commoad npm install -g appium@2.0,it does not get any error but when try appium command it gives not recognized as an internal or external command.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWWGz.png)

I have tried this and getting this error